# Can I build an Apache Ant task and execute it in the same step?

Tags: java, ant, taskdef

Is it possible to create an Apache Ant build.xml that can create a task in one target and subsequently use it in another target?

Here is a simple `build.xml` to illustrate this:

```
<project name="BuildAndUseTask" default="use-task">
    <!-- Define the task -->
    <taskdef name="testtask"
        classname="org.example.TestTask"/>

    <!-- Compile the task -->
    <target name="compile-task">
        <javac srcdir="task/src" destdir="."/>
    </target>

    <!-- Use the task -->
    <target name="use-task" depends="compile-task">
        <testtask option="something"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

The output I get is:

```
Buildfile: /path/to/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/path/to/build.xml:5: taskdef class org.example.TestTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

Is this possible to do this as a single step without resorting to using nested Ant executions?  I am working around this separately by first commenting the `<taskdef>`, explicitly building the `compile-task` target, uncommenting the `<taskdef>`, and finally build the `use-task` target.

Comment: https://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html#taskcontainer specifically "Example 2".

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you. That works.  It was not clear to me that the `<taskdef>` had to a) follow the task's build target, and b) reside inside a target.  I assume it's done that way to order via dependencies.

Comment: Great; glad you worked it out!